# Join table 1 with 2. If no values found in table 2 fetch from table 3

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to join table 1 `T1` with table 2 `T2` on `LEID` and pull some values `ISIC Code` from `T2` for the joined values.

If I don't get values `ISIC Code` from `T2` for the `LEID`, I want to check the same from table 3 basis the same joining attribute.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also, choose MySQL or Oracle.  They are not hte ame think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want two `left join`s.  I think it would look like this:

```
select . . ., coalesce(t2.isic, t3.isic) as isic
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.leid = t2.leid left join
     t3
     on t1.leid = t3.leid and t2.leid is null;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for the revert. This seems to be working fine. However, is there a way I can use the coalesced attribute (isic in this case) in my subsequent query

Comment: @user3532090 . . . I don't understand your question.  You can use `isic` in the `on` clause.  If that's not what you mean, ask another question.

Comment: After the above query, I wanna filter only those records where isic <> t1.attribute. Doing this however gives an error.

Comment: @user3532090 . . . just use `where coalesce(t2.isic, t3.isic) <> t1.attribute`.